# Is dup2() equivalent to the following subsequent call in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I am writing a half-duplex pipe function in Linux. In the example, a child process is forked and then I use the child process to write the message. Thus, I am closing the std-in ( file descriptor = 0). This is done using the following code.

```
dup2(0,m_pipe_desc[0]); , Is this call equivalent to 

close(0)
dup(m_pipe_desc[0]);
```

On the other hand, for the parent process ( used for reading the message). I am closing the 
stdout, and using the m_pipe_desc[1]. Can I use the following function here.

```
dup2(1, m_pipe_desc[1]).
```

Is this call equivalent to -

```
close(1)
dup(m_pipe_desc[1]);
```

The man page is confusing here -

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dup.html

However, the example shown in this website says different - 
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html

Here is my understanding -
 int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);

makes newfd be the copy of oldfd.

This is useful to close the stdin, and instead use the pipe fd[0]. 
For example,

dup2(STDIN,fd[0]);

For a Reader process -  dup2(STDOUT,fd[1]);

Comment: For 0 both forms are the same.  For 1 they are the same unless 0 happens to be closed.

Comment: I'd say, that they are not the same even for 0 if we have multiple threads, e.g. other thread calling simply `dup` might use just `close`d descriptor 0 or 1.